# Ubuntu 22.04 kills nvme on HP Pavilion 15-eh2003nu

Tags: partitioning, nvme, hp-pavilion

As title says. During installation (erase everything option) ubi-partman exits with code 10, nvme becomes undetectable to even bios diagnostics. First time reseating helped. Second time I left it with the technicians longer, and they claim that it killed another. The nvme is some kioxia 512gb drive.
Anyone have an idea what could be causing this, and if I can actually use this device with ubuntu, or should try to return it?

Comment: If resetting helped then it may be the motherboard and or the drive not the Ubuntu software.

Comment: It killed a different drive of the same brand

Comment: I have a more versed friend claiming that SecureBoot could be the cause, leading to an encrypted and corrupted drive.

Comment: Also, windows worked fine for the techs.

Comment: Secure boot should be off when dual boot.